# Nodejs application crashes upon visiting form page

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am following along a Udemy tutorial. So far, everything was running fine until I connected the application to mongodb. The application runs fine, connects to the database but when I visit the form page, which is supposed to display data from the database, application crashes and gives me the following error.

app.js file

```js
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var appRoutes = require('./routes/app');

var app = express();
mongoose.connect('localhost:27017/node-angular2');

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS');
    next();
});

app.use('/', appRoutes);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    return res.render('index');
});


module.exports = app;
```

router/app.js

```js
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var User = require('../models/user');

router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {

    User.findOne({}, function(err, doc) {
        if (err) {
            return res.send('Error!');
        }
        res.render('node', {email: doc.email});
    });
});

router.post('/', function(req, res, next) {
    var email = req.body.email;
    var user = new User({
        firstName: 'Max',
        lastName: 'Schwarz',
        password: 'super-secret',
        email: this.email
    });
    user.save();
    res.redirect('/');
});

module.exports = router;
```

Error Log

```
> node ./bin/www

events.js:160
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'email' of null
    at /Users/farooqkhan/Documents/Udemy/node-angular2/routes/app.js:11:39
    at Query.<anonymous> (/Users/farooqkhan/Documents/Udemy/node-angular2/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:3381:16)
    at /Users/farooqkhan/Documents/Udemy/node-angular2/node_modules/kareem/index.js:259:21
    at /Users/farooqkhan/Documents/Udemy/node-angular2/node_modules/kareem/index.js:127:16
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:67:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)

npm ERR! Darwin 16.1.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "start"
npm ERR! node v6.9.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.8
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! udemy-nodejs-angular2@1.0.0 start: `node ./bin/www`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the udemy-nodejs-angular2@1.0.0 start script 'node ./bin/www'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the udemy-nodejs-angular2 package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node ./bin/www
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs udemy-nodejs-angular2
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls udemy-nodejs-angular2
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/farooqkhan/Documents/Udemy/node-angular2/npm-debug.log
```

2nd Example.

Then I ran a mongodb IDE, I got from github. It used to work fine but now when I visit the homepage it also gives the following error:

```
> node app.js

(node:1054) fs: re-evaluating native module sources is not supported. If you are using the graceful-fs module, please update it to a more recent version.
adminMongo listening on host: http://0.0.0.0:1234
GET / 302 8.496 ms - 56
/Users/farooqkhan/Documents/mongoIDE/adminMongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js:237
          throw err
          ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined
    at module.exports (/Users/farooqkhan/Documents/mongoIDE/adminMongo/node_modules/parse-mongo-url/index.js:10:10)
    at new Database (/Users/farooqkhan/Documents/mongoIDE/adminMongo/node_modules/mongojs/lib/database.js:43:20)
    at module.exports (/Users/farooqkhan/Documents/mongoIDE/adminMongo/node_modules/mongojs/index.js:5:12)
    at /Users/farooqkhan/Documents/mongoIDE/adminMongo/routes/index.js:58:22
    at connectCallback (/Users/farooqkhan/Documents/mongoIDE/adminMongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js:315:5)
    at /Users/farooqkhan/Documents/mongoIDE/adminMongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js:234:11
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:67:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)

npm ERR! Darwin 16.1.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "start"
npm ERR! node v6.9.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.8
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! admin-mongo@0.0.3 start: `node app.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the admin-mongo@0.0.3 start script 'node app.js'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the admin-mongo package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node app.js
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs admin-mongo
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls admin-mongo
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/farooqkhan/Documents/mongoIDE/adminMongo/npm-debug.log
```

I dont understand whats wrong here. Everything used to work fine I dont know what happened suddenly. I even tried re-installing MongoDB but nothing helped.

Comment: Sources of your `app.js` files and error logs would be more helpful than error logs only.

Comment: You will need the body-parser module installed as middleware in order for the `req.body` property to properly contain your form data.  You must have missed that step from the example you were following.

Comment: body-parser is imported in the main app.js file. The above code is from routes/app.js

Comment: Well, `req.body` is empty so you're not doing something correct with body-parser.  Show us that code if you want us to help.  Your second error is apparently something else.

Comment: I added the code from main app.js file.

Comment: Try changing this.email to only email. 
email: email
Maybe you are trying to access this from a scope where email is not defined.

Comment: Just tried that. Didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the collection doesn't have a data, can you verify that your node-angular2 modules have user table and it has data?

You can do this by a third party tool like robomongo or through shell connect with mongo command.

meanwhile you can modify your code to do some error handling

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var User = require('../models/user');

router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {

    User.findOne({}, function(err, doc) {
        if (err) {
            return res.send('Error!');
        }
        if(doc){
           res.render('node', {email: doc.email});
        }else{
           res.render('node', {email: null});
        }
    });
});

router.post('/', function(req, res, next) {
    var email = req.body.email;
    var user = new User({
        firstName: 'Max',
        lastName: 'Schwarz',
        password: 'super-secret',
        email: email
    });
    user.save(function(err){
       if(err){
         console.log("couldn't save");
       }
       res.redirect('/');
    });
});
module.exports = router;
```

As you can see I have modified your post call and am calling redirect in the callback of save function, which means it will redirect only when user is saved.

when res.json or res.redirect is called without completing the previous operation, previous operations are cancelled inherently.

Comment: Works perfectly fine. Thank you so much for your help. I appreciate it.